# "Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::$

Tags: php, html, vue.js

I am getting this error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::${"id":1,"title":"abddad","description":"abddad.","created_at":"2019-06-27 22:25:18","updated_at":"2019-06-27 22:25:18"} (View: /home/vagrant/projectos/projectofinal/ProjectoFinal/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

The code is the following:

```
@foreach (\App\Award::all()->take(3) as $award)
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> 
      <ul class="timeline">
          @if (count($this->$award) === 2)
          <li>
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="img/awards/medal.png">
          </div>
          @else 
          <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="img/awards/medal.png">
          </div>
          @endif
          <div class="timeline-panel">            
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="subheading">{{ $award->title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">{{ $award->description }}</p>
            </div>          
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>       
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
```

If i use $award instead of $this->award

I have the error:

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: /home/vagrant/projectos/projectofinal/ProjectoFinal/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

Getting the error exception in the 5th line "@if (count($this->$award) === 2)"

What should i do different?

Hope this helps
dd($award):

```
  Award {#692 ▼
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "awards"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
 #perPage: 15
 +exists: true
 +wasRecentlyCreated: false
 #attributes: array:5 [▶]
 #original: array:5 [▶]
 #changes: []
 #casts: []
 #dates: []
 #dateFormat: null
 #appends: []
 #dispatchesEvents: []
 #observables: []
 #relations: []
 #touches: []
 +timestamps: true
 #hidden: []
 #visible: []
 #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Comment: please do update your question with full error

Comment: which is 5th line and what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: that should only be  `$award` instead of `$this->award` !

Comment: can you `dd` $award and let us know what you get?

Comment: did your try this `@if (count($award) === 2)`

Comment: Add your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

following code is calling property of $this by value of variable $award
    ($this->$award)
means that if $award does contain string matching property of $this, you should get value of that property.

Instead, $award contains something that looks like a stringified json object

```
{"id":1,"title":"abddad","description":"abddad.","created_at":"2019-06-27 22:25:18","updated_at":"2019-06-27 22:25:18"}
```

however $this does not contain such variable.

try following code on line 5, should work

```
@if (count($award) === 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this

```
@if (($award->id) % 2 == "0")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thats incorrect. what if you get id (3,4,5,6... and so on). ?